# Как открыть карту сети в windows или построить её самому?

Tags: c++, c, windows, сеть, cmd

Я нашёл как открыть центр управления сетями и общим доступом: `control.exe /name Microsoft.NetworkAndSharingCenter`.

Чтобы открыть карту можно нажать "Просмотр полной карты".
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Мне надо открыть именно карту сети, можно ли это сделать с помощью С++ или cmd?
Мне в программе необходимо показывать карту сети, как вариант я думал открыть встроенную, но если с этим не выйдет, то где я могу взять в таком случае данных, по которым смогу сам построить карту сети?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Мне надо открыть именно карту сети, можно ли это сделать с помощью С++ или cmd?

Для программного вызова карты сети можно использовать вызов explorer.exe с передачей в командной строке пути к элементу панели управления (Shell namespace path):

```
system("%systemroot%\\explorer.exe \"::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\\0\\::{E7DE9B1A-7533-4556-9484-B26FB486475E}\"");
```

где:

**%systemroot%\explorer.exe** - полный путь к explorer (короткий путь не пашет!)
**{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}** - CLSID Панели Управления
**{E7DE9B1A-7533-4556-9484-B26FB486475E}** - CLSID Карты сети

По крайней мере, так работает в Windows 7. Если CLSID в других ОС отличается, его можно узнать поиском "NetworkMap" в реестре. Или открыв NetworkMap, выбрав в контекстном меню адресной строки элемент "Копировать адрес", и вставив его сюда же в адресную строку.

> где я могу взять в таком случае данных, по которым смогу сам построить
>   карту сети?

Для получения списка устройств в текущем сегменте сети используется протокол SSDP. Нужно отправить запрос **M-SEARCH** через UDP на мультикаст-адрес **239.255.255.250:1900**, затем собирать приходящие ответы. Подробнее [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/328726/).